# How to reduce the number of endpoints in a SOAP service to speed up service.getPort()?

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, jax-ws

I am supposed to consume a few specific endpoints in a massively huge SOAP API, and when I `wsimport` the WSDL I get 1855 individual action classes created, of which I need about 13.

I have tried to carve out all the unnecessary things from the WSDL file but (a) there are still generated 1847 proxy objects (I didn't carve up the XSD file) and (b) I'm getting errors from wsimport saying "no valid ports found".

Other than trial-and-error in carving up the WSDL and XSD files manually (ugh, 33,000 lines!)(Eclipse's design view only lets me delete one-by-one), are there any tools that will let me isolate a subset of this huge WS offering so that I'm not carrying around all the baggage of endpoints and value classes I'll never use?

Edit: Found this, basically the same question: [Working with large wsdl, can we trim it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402160/working-with-large-wsdl-can-we-trim-it). Since it was asked 6 years ago, and I'm hoping someone's made some progress since then, I'm not closing this as duplicate just yet.