# SOAP based WebServices and WSDL

Tags: scala, soap, wsdl

I have a SOAP based WebServices that I should consume. The WSDL file for this service contains 50 different operations and is 1000 lines in content. Out of these 50 different operations, I only use a handful of them. So here are my questions:

1. Can I trim this WSDL down to the set of services that I need? I can then keep a local copy of this WSDL and do the code generation when building my project.
2. Are there any potential dis-advatages of using this approach to trim the WSDL on the client?

Is there any good Scala based libraries that I could use?

Comment: possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402160/working-with-large-wsdl-can-we-trim-it

Comment: Not sure it's an exact duplicate but it's close

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I trim this WSDL down to the set of services that I need?

Yes. I've done exactly this before

> Are there any potential dis-advatages of using this approach to trim
>   the WSDL on the client?

Depends. If you're building a client library for use by other code, you've just limited what they can do. If it's all your code, it makes it more of a pain if you find you need to add one to that handful of methods you need.

If the WSDL gets updated and re-released, you have to do your edits again.

And any change you made to the WSDL always introduces the chance of an error

> Is there any good Scala based libraries that I could use?

Asking for recommendations for libraries is off topic. However, [scalaxb](http://scalaxb.org/wsdl-support) maybe?

Comment: If I use scalaxb, why should I bother installing it? I just want to add that as a dependency and when I compile, I tell the plugin to generate the client classes! Is that how scalaxb works?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, but there is documentation on how to use it with maven or sbt on the scalaxb site.

Comment: Yes that documentation is not just good enough! I'm trying out some examples with a simple WSDL file and I'm just not making any progress! http://scalaxb.org/wsdl-support

Comment: Sorry, can't help, probably. I tried scalaxb a while back and it was then lacking support for some features of the WSDL I was using, so I didn't pursue it. Try the mailing list? It seems active